# Flutter methods jumps before it gets completed

Tags: flutter

When in debugging mode I discovered that my method

`DatabaseProvider.db.insert(newShift).then((storedShift) {...}`

jumps to the next one before completing all the steps and comes latter back to complete them.

I read the [Flutter .then method](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Future/then.html) documentation which states that if the **.then** future is already completed, the inner callback will not be called immediately, but will be scheduled in a later microtask.

How can I manage it so that the callback found within the **.then** method is completed immediately after?

[image]

Here is the complete Code:

```
onPressed: () {
                    _formKey.currentState.save();
                    // for the Database
                    Shift newShift = new Shift(
                        dateOfShift: _dateOfShift,
                        dateOfShiftString: _dateformat.format(_dateOfShift),
//                        dateOfShiftString: new DateFormat.yMd(_dateOfShift),
                        startOfShiftTime: _startOfShiftTime,
                        endOfShiftTime: _endOfShiftTime,
                        designation: _designation,
                        employee: _employee,
                        // when creating a new shift there is no index. Thus it takes the value -1
                        indexForWidget: _indexForWidget);

                    DatabaseProvider.db.insert(newShift).then((storedShift) {
                      // get the id of the db
                      print(newShift);
                      // insert to database
                      BlocProvider.of<ShiftBloc>(context).add(
                        AddShift(storedShift),
                      );
                      // get the id of the db
                      print(newShift);
                    });
                    // insert to the static Map
                    if (customEvents[_dateOfShift] != null) {
                      // in case this is the first shift for this date
                      customEvents[_dateOfShift]
                          .add(_buildShiftContainer(shift: newShift));
                    } else {
                      // in case there are already registered shifts
                      customEvents[_dateOfShift] = [
                        _buildShiftContainer(shift: newShift)
                      ];
                    }
                    // giving back an object
                    Navigator.pop(context, newShift);
                  }
```